# Why doesn't Audio MIDI Setup connect over wi-fi in Monterey?

Tags: monterey, apple-silicon, midi

I routinely open Audio MIDI Setup on my Mac, click one of my iOS devices that is on the same wi-fi network, and click the Connect button to initiate a MIDI connection. That's all it takes to send MIDI back and forth over wi-fi.

But last fall I got an Apple Silicon Mac with macOS 12 Monterey, and on this machine, the Connect button is always disabled. I don't know if the problem is with the Apple processor or Monterey, but the setup I've routinely used before has never worked on this machine.

I thought it might be a bug in macOS 12, but I'm now on 12.3 and it remains. Do I need to turn something on somewhere to activate this function? Google searches have turned up no other examples of people seeing this problem; is it specific to me?

[image: Disabled Connect button in Audio MIDI Setup]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by searching for "directory" in the [Audio MIDI Setup User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/audio-midi-setup/welcome/mac). As shown in my original screen shot, there was nothing listed under My Sessions. I had to click + to add a session, then enter a Local Name and Bonjour Name on the right (I just entered my computer name), then check the checkbox next to the session name. Then the Connect button under Directory became enabled like normal.

When working, the window looks like this:

[image: Enabled Connect button]

More detailed instructions are here:

https://support.apple.com/guide/audio-midi-setup/share-midi-information-over-a-network-ams1012/3.5/mac/12.0